# Select row from one query where opposites are not present in second query

Tags: mysql

Hopefully this explanation will clear up what the question is asking for ...

I have 2 tables (I'll populate them a little too):

**inbox**

```
---------------|-----------------
| to_USER_id   |   MESSAGE_id   |
---------------|-----------------
|       2      |         1      |
|       3      |         2      |
|       4      |         3      |
---------------------------------
```

**message**

```
---------------|----------------------------------
|     id       |  from_USER_id   |    content    |
--------------------------------------------------
|      1       |        4        |      Hey      |
|      2       |        1        |     Hello     |
|      3       |        2        |   How's it..  |
--------------------------------------------------
```

Basically, these are the tables that hold data when messages are 'sent' from one user to another. I need to work out a query (MySQL) that will return the `message.id`, which does not have an `inbox.to_USER_id` the same as the  `message.from_USER_id` (Basically, which message has not been replied to)

So, as you may be able to see, user 4 messages user 2. Then user 1 messages user 3. Then user 2 replies to user 4.

How do I query these tables to only return the `message.id` which has not yet had a reply. So, in this case it will return the row where a message was sent from user 1, which has not got a reply from user 3.

It's quite hard to explain ... But hopefully someone understands

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  m.id
    FROM  message AS m
    WHERE  NOT EXISTS 
      ( SELECT  *
            FROM  inbox AS i
            WHERE  i.message_id = m.id
              AND  i.to_user_id = m.from_user_id 
      )
```

I think it could also be cone with a `LEFT JOIN` (with similar efficiency), but `NOT EXISTS` more closely matches your description of the task.

Comment: Thanks, your answer got my brain working a little, and managed to get it working using `NOT IN` rather than `NOT EXISTS`. I wont post the full results, because I still don't think my question actually makes sense Lol ... I'll probably delete this question tomorrow, just wanted to say thanks for your time :D

Comment: Keep in mind that `[NOT] IN ( SELECT ... )` is inefficient.  You explained it well enough for me to figure out what you wanted.

Comment: I'll put what I did as an answer, so that you can see ... Again, I think it's because I have simplified my tables, and my explanation is not clear Lol ...

Answer (score 0):

This answer is just to explain a comment

```
SELECT id
FROM message
WHERE from_USER_id NOT IN
    (SELECT to_USER_id
    FROM inbox 
    LEFT JOIN message ON message.id=inbox.MESSAGE_id)
```